# Multiple query substitution in PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

As in PHP multiple queries are not supported using mysql_query(), how could I convert the following code to become a unique query ?

I precise that I can't change my database to MySQLi or anything else.

```
SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM hierarchie WHERE id = ".$father_id.";
UPDATE hierarchie SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
UPDATE hierarchie SET lft = lft+2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;
INSERT INTO hierarchie VALUES(".$cat.", ".$id.", '".$fullindi."', @myLeft+1, @myLeft+2);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Best regards.

UPDATE :

Answering to my own question, I found the link : http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/multiple-mysql-queries where the author expalins how to do it.

For me, and following his explanations, the code becomes :

```
$sql = "
SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM hierarchie WHERE id = ".$father_id.";
UPDATE hierarchie SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
UPDATE hierarchie SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;
INSERT INTO hierarchie VALUES(".$cat.", ".$id.", '".$fullindi."', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);
";
$queries = preg_split("/;+(?=([^'|^\\\']*['|\\\'][^'|^\\\']*['|\\\'])*[^'|^\\\']*[^'|^\\\']$)/", $sql);
foreach ($queries as $query){
   if (strlen(trim($query)) > 0) mysql_query($query);
}
```

I've tested and it works well.

We can consider the problem is resolved, except if one of you has a better solution.

Comment: why not just run multiple `mysql_query()` commands?

Comment: @JohnP, he cannot run multiple commands since he needs to use the results of one in the others.

Comment: @JohnP : That's precisely the reason why I needed a single-shot query, as said itsols.

Comment: @itsols, whoops! should have paid more attention to the queries themselves. @mlh, if the solution you found worked, you should post it as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: @itsols but @mlh ended up running multiple queries anyway.

Comment: yeah.. instead of running like query="" mysql_query($query).. for multiple times.. mlh is doing the same with a loop with his suggested answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) so you can execute those queries separately but they will be considered as one.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

So, for instance, the example above will require 4 mysql_query() commands but mysql will execute the whole thing as one query;

Comment: mmm so what is the transaction for?

Comment: yes, probably I should have mentioned that in the answer, but it is written in the linked page

Comment: Are you sure you want to "lunch" the queries?